# Custom design TabBar in iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I want to make a custom design tabbar, like the image below.
[image: custom tabbar]

What is the right way to do this? I started to build my own solution for this, but maybe an inheritance from UITabBarController would be better.
That way I only found solution for changing the icon color, or the position, but I need more.

Any idea? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.
I use the standard `UITabBarController`, but with hidden tabBar, then added some custom look button to the top.

To hide tabBar:
type in `viewDidLoad`

```
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setTranslucent:YES];
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:YES];
```

Custom buttons with programatically tab switch

```
- (IBAction)secoundView:(id)sender {
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
}
- (IBAction)firstView:(id)sender {
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
}
```

[image: custom buttons]

Answer (score 1):

I have similar issue. I used a `UIVew` inside which I draw several `UIButtons` which correspond to my tabs. Bellow it I have `UITableView`. When I click a button I reloaded `UITableView`.

It is very easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution would be using one of those countless libraries for this, such as:

https://github.com/iltercengiz/ICViewPager

Answer (score 0):

you can use UIView and UIButton control to create custom tab control.you can get idea from [here](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tuc-the-unit-converter/id917679536?ls=1&mt=8)